# jquery, wait for completed

Tags: jquery

how to run the second function only when the first will be completed in?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#first").load("first.php?id="+ Math.random());
 $("#second").load("second.php?id="+ Math.random());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load()` comes with a callback parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#first").load("first.php?id="+ Math.random(), {}, function() {
  $("#second").load("second.php?id="+ Math.random());
 });
});
```

The `{}` is for passing an empty object to the `data` parameter.